# locked out of my phone

Tags: lock-screens

I have a galaxy s4 and I put a lock on it.  I don't know the pin code.  I tried using android device manager and it reset my lock code, but still says its the wrong password or pin.  I have reset it over 20 times.  It always says its the wrong password or pin.  I have switched it up to see if it matters.  The keyboard changes to fit my password or pin, so i know its updating and changing the password.  Is there any way at ALL to unlock it or fix android device manager with out factory resetting it?  Please.  I cant lose everything on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Tyler the Android device manager works if you had previously set it up before hand, as well as Samsung's find my mobile.

When you use the device manager, are you able to see it on the map? Can you click ring to see if it responds? If so then you should be able to reset your lockscreen. After you reset the lockscreen password, the device should change its lockscreen from a pin to a black transparent bar to input your newly made password. Also make sure that the right device is selected when doing this.

If the lockscreen doesn't change try turning off the device for a few seconds then power on. Make sure the device has Internet connection as well. If none of the so solutions work, your only option would be to hard reset the device.